# Make paint event for datagridview work for all datagridviews in project

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Not sure what to search for on this
 in the paint event code listed below it paints gridlines to fill the blank space of the datagridview without having to add blank rows
 this code does work but I still making mods to it
what I want to find out how to do is make the event part of all my datagridviews without having to repeat and modify the code 
for instance I have 8 datagridviews that can use it I don't want to have to have 8 copies of this in my code the optimum way would be to have a gridline property set on each datagridview and if its true then use the below code to paint the lines

But as it stands right now I have to put this code as an event for every datagridview

I don't want code written for me but need suggestions on where to start

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint
        Dim intRowHeight As Integer
        Dim intTopOffset As Integer
        Dim intLeftOffset As Integer
        Dim objRowImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap
        Dim objGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
        Dim objRowFrame As System.Drawing.Rectangle
        Dim objRowFill As System.Drawing.Rectangle
        Dim objRowHeaderFrame As System.Drawing.Rectangle
        Dim intIndex As Integer
        Dim intLastIndex As Integer
        Dim intRowHeadersWidth As Integer
        If DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows Then
            intLastIndex = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex
        Else
            intLastIndex = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        End If
        If DataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible Then
            intRowHeadersWidth = DataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth
        Else
            intRowHeadersWidth = 1
        End If
        intRowHeight = DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height
        intTopOffset = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight + intRowHeight * (intLastIndex + 1)
        If DataGridView1.Height - intTopOffset > intRowHeight Then
            objRowImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(DataGridView1.Width, intRowHeight)
            objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(objRowImage)
            objRowFrame = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, DataGridView1.Width, intRowHeight)
            objGraphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.SystemPens.ControlDark, objRowFrame)
            objRowFill = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(1, 1, DataGridView1.Width - 2, intRowHeight - 2)
            objGraphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.SystemBrushes.Window, objRowFill)
            objRowHeaderFrame = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(2, 2, intRowHeadersWidth - 2, intRowHeight - 4)
            objGraphics.FillRectangle(New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(DataGridView1.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), objRowHeaderFrame)
            intLeftOffset = intRowHeadersWidth
            For Each objColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn In DataGridView1.Columns
                If objColumn.Visible Then
                    intLeftOffset += objColumn.Width
                    objGraphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.SystemPens.ControlDark, New System.Drawing.Point(intLeftOffset, 0), New System.Drawing.Point(intLeftOffset, intRowHeight))
                End If
            Next objColumn
            intIndex = (DataGridView1.Height - intTopOffset) \ intRowHeight
            For j As Integer = 0 To intIndex
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(objRowImage, 0, intTopOffset + j * intRowHeight)
            Next j
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add all of your DataGridViews after the `Handles` keyword:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) _
    Handles DataGridView1.Paint, DataGridView2.Paint, DataGridView3.Paint, etc...
```

Next, cast the `sender` parameter to a DataGridView:

```
    Dim DG As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
```

Finally change all of the code to use `DG` instead of `DataGridView1`:

```
Private Sub DG_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DG.Paint, DataGridView2.Paint, DataGridView3.Paint
    Dim DG As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)

    Dim intRowHeight As Integer
    Dim intTopOffset As Integer
    Dim intLeftOffset As Integer
    Dim objRowImage As System.Drawing.Bitmap
    Dim objGraphics As System.Drawing.Graphics
    Dim objRowFrame As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Dim objRowFill As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Dim objRowHeaderFrame As System.Drawing.Rectangle
    Dim intIndex As Integer
    Dim intLastIndex As Integer
    Dim intRowHeadersWidth As Integer
    If DG.AllowUserToAddRows Then
        intLastIndex = DG.NewRowIndex
    Else
        intLastIndex = DG.Rows.Count - 1
    End If
    If DG.RowHeadersVisible Then
        intRowHeadersWidth = DG.RowHeadersWidth
    Else
        intRowHeadersWidth = 1
    End If
    intRowHeight = DG.RowTemplate.Height
    intTopOffset = DG.ColumnHeadersHeight + intRowHeight * (intLastIndex + 1)
    If DG.Height - intTopOffset > intRowHeight Then
        objRowImage = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(DG.Width, intRowHeight)
        objGraphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(objRowImage)
        objRowFrame = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, DG.Width, intRowHeight)
        objGraphics.DrawRectangle(System.Drawing.SystemPens.ControlDark, objRowFrame)
        objRowFill = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(1, 1, DG.Width - 2, intRowHeight - 2)
        objGraphics.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.SystemBrushes.Window, objRowFill)
        objRowHeaderFrame = New System.Drawing.Rectangle(2, 2, intRowHeadersWidth - 2, intRowHeight - 4)
        objGraphics.FillRectangle(New System.Drawing.SolidBrush(DG.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor), objRowHeaderFrame)
        intLeftOffset = intRowHeadersWidth
        For Each objColumn As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn In DG.Columns
            If objColumn.Visible Then
                intLeftOffset += objColumn.Width
                objGraphics.DrawLine(System.Drawing.SystemPens.ControlDark, New System.Drawing.Point(intLeftOffset, 0), New System.Drawing.Point(intLeftOffset, intRowHeight))
            End If
        Next objColumn
        intIndex = (DG.Height - intTopOffset) \ intRowHeight
        For j As Integer = 0 To intIndex
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(objRowImage, 0, intTopOffset + j * intRowHeight)
        Next j
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this worked, I will look at the other answers and see which one works better

Comment: This will not _work for all datagridviews in the project_. Only for datagridviews in the one form.

Comment: @Fabio, true.  This is a "quick fix".  AddHandler would work well too.  My solution is a **design-time** approach while yours is at **run-time**.  A better approach would be to **Inherit** from DataGridView and override the Paint() event.  Then you'd use that new DataGridView control at the top of the ToolBox instead of the Stock one.  This would require lots of changes however...

Comment: I see the issue not working in entire project, I will definitely take it to the next level so that it is its own toolbox control, but after I finish this current project thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Simply make your own version of the datagridview.

Create a new class, inherit Datagridview, add some functionality to the paint event plus the new property, rebuild the affected project and use your new class as though is were the original with some extra features... cause it is.

```
Public Class mdgv
    Inherits DataGridView
    Property doit As Boolean = False
    Private Sub mdgv_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        If doit = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("painted")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, replace your current DATAGRIDVIEW objects with the new class, MDGV. Hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make you method `Shared` inside some class or put it inside of `Module`
After this your event handler can be used in the different forms across project
Then as was mentioned by @idle_Mind, cast `sender` object to the `DataGridView` type and use inside your event handler

```vb
Public Module YourSomeModule
    Public Sub DataGridView_MyHandlerPaint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
        'Cast instance of the DataGridView from "sender" object
        'Name it same as in your code, 
        'then you don't need to change name in the code
        '(If you not used "Me.DataGridView", if so just remove "Me.")

        Dim DataGridView1 As DataGridView = DirectCast(sender, DataGridView)
        'Here your code
    End Sub
End Public
```

Then only thing you need to do - add handler to the `Paint` event of datagridview in the form.
Do it in the constructor after `Me.Initialize()` method

```
Public Class MyForm1

    Public Sub New()
         Me.Initialize()
         AddHandler Me.DataGridView1.Paint, 
                    AddressOf YourSomeModule.DataGridView_MyHandlerPaint
    End Sub

End Class
```

Another Form

```
Public Class MyForm2

    Public Sub New()
         Me.Initialize()
         AddHandler Me.DataGridView2.Paint, 
                    AddressOf YourSomeModule.DataGridView_MyHandlerPaint
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I am trying this one next